# Application stopped work after update

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

**Background story:**

Hello, i run an application based on c# and windows forms. Back in 2006 i overrided some windows forms components to make my own component library, which run on .net framework since then.

After a recent update on my main application, which references the described library, few customers experienced the "Application.exe has stopped working" when showing a tooltip on list grid items.

**Problem:**

I can't reproduce the error on any computer or VM. The error seems to occur on random machines, with different OS like:

- Win 7 x86
- Win 7 x64
- Win 8 x64
- Win 10 x86

Some standard attempts have been made (most of them were tested on different VMs and different OS builds):

1. Reboot the system
2. Reinstall the application
3. Build project in x86 and AnyCPU
4. Update customers .net framework to latest version
5. Reinstall customer's .net framework
6. Update application's framework to 4.5
7. Update DLL's framework to 4.0
8. Install some of the customer's programs (like office, java), copied the customer's environment variables aswell in order to make my environment the most similar to the customers as possible .

**Clues**

After some effort doing these tests, i started to make remote debug on my customers. I tried to use Windows dump file several times, comming up with the error line of the code below:

```
void ShowToolTip()
            {
               //tooltip rises after mouse is 1sec over a grid item.
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
               lock (_lock)
               {
                   if (_toolTipState == FLToolTipState.Hide || ToolTipControl != null)
                       return;
                   Owner.Invoke(new Action<Object>((scope) =>
                   {
                       try { OnShowToolTip(); }
                       catch (NullReferenceException) { return; }

                       //calling Windows forms tool tip override
                       ToolTipControl = new FLToolTipControl() { OwnerGrid = Owner };
                       ToolTipControl.Source = new FLToolTipControl.FLToolTipItem(this) { Owner = Owner };
                       ToolTipControl.UpdatePosition();

                       //this is the "stopped working" point
                       //Show is from System.Windows.Forms.Form
                       ToolTipControl.Show();

                   }), this);
                   _toolTipState = FLToolTipState.Showed;
               }
            }
```

Some dump files came up with ThreadAborException, others came with AccessViolationException, both on the above method. Following stack traces from DUMP:

**ThreadAbortException**

> System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32)
>   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Int32)
>   MyCustomLibrary.WinForms.Grouping.Sections.Section.ShowToolTip()
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

**AccessViolationException**

> System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.GdipFillPath(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef)
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.FillPath(System.Drawing.Brush,
>   System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath)
>   MyCustomLibrary.WinForms.Grouping.Utility.GdiPlusEx.FillRoundRect(System.Drawing.Graphics,
>   System.Drawing.Brush, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)
>   MyCustomLibrary.WinForms.Grouping.Utility.GdiPlusEx.FillRoundRect(System.Drawing.Graphics,
>   System.Drawing.Brush, System.Drawing.Rectangle, Int32)
>   MyCustomLibrary.WinForms.Grouping.Helper.FLToolTipControl.OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs,
>   Int16)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmEraseBkgnd(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) 
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr)

Recently, in a few customers, application stops working when Chrome or Adobe Reader is initialized, but is also kinda random.

In customers running Win 7 x86, starting the application in compatibility mode with XP SP2 worked, but not on customers who run Win 8 or 10.

Again, i'm comming here as my last resource, as i said, is a quite random bug, since this form library is running since 2006. I made code review from the latest patch aswell on my main application, but i found nothing.

Any idea on how to reproduce this issue would be grat, thank you!

Comment: The GDI error is more a sign of Out of Memory or a silent memory corruption. The ThreadAbortException is induced by someone by calling thread abort. You are playing with fire when calling Owner.Invoke if the caller is already on the UI thread because this invoke will drain all pending window messages before your to be invoked call will be executed. This can cause reentrancy issues againts which your lock will not help at all. That can break invariants you try to guard against with the lock. First you should check with Owner.InvokeRequired if you need to invoke at all.

Comment: Thank you Alois. But this problem remains unsolved.
The solution i found to this problem is to rollback this overrides and use original win forms tooltip.